# SQL - insert new row depends on previous data from same table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table with **Car** name. Here is a pseudo-table :

[image]

This table has been fallen with data like :

```
order = 14214
type = 0
created = 2017-12-10 23:39:23
```

I want to some operation with this data :

1 - find data till 6 days ago.

2 -  (For each records of step 1) 
I want to insert new record with order same as step1.order and with type= `1`.

For first step , I found out I use

```
select *  
from cars
WHERe `created` <= Date(Now()) - INTERVAL 6 day
```

but for next step,  Is there any suggestion?

EDITED:  :

Ex . I had a table with 250 records, after inserting new data, my table would be 500 rows with A table and A' (B&B',...) for each order.

Comment: `INSERT INTO .... select ... 
from cars
WHERE created <= Date(Now()) - INTERVAL 6 day`  ??

Comment: You need to use ORDER BY

Comment: @RaymondNijland put your query as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below script.

Note: I assume ID field is auto-increment primary key.

```
insert into cars (`order`, type, created)
select `order`, 1 type, created  
from cars
WHERe `created` <= Date(Now()) - INTERVAL 6 day
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY`